# What does a correlation error mean on an editform.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Okay I tried this method of creating a new editform and modifying it, this page is viewable https://teams8.uspublicsector.ssn.xx.com/sites/GSSTA/TA/LOAD/Lists/Opportunity%20Dashboard%20%20Pursuit%20Mgt/4.0/EditForm_Custom_PM.aspx

Did new from existing page

Saved as https://teams8.uspublicsector.ssn.xx.com/sites/GSSTA/TA/LOAD/Lists/Opportunity%20Dashboard%20%20Pursuit%20Mgt/4.0/EditForm_Custom_PM_2.aspx

Did preview in browser and that worked

Inserted 6 blank rows and clicked save then tried to browse again

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:2483e57e-ccbc-4790-b2ff-7334cd53c894

If I delete 6 blank rows I can view….

Comment: you know that posting your real links is not very save and also useless since we don't have access?

Answer (score 0):

Correlation Ids are GUIDs assigned to events which transpire during the lifecycle of a resource request.  As problems occur, the Correlation Id is commonly surfaced within the context of an error when presented to the person initiating the request.

An administrator can then use the Correlation Id to locate and isolate the request in the ULS log.

So if you are using the SharePoint On-prem then search for the correlation id in the ULS logs on server and you will get complete error trace, why it is occurring. You can use [Merge-spLogfile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) powershell command to get the details from all servers.

But if you are using the O365 then you have to contact the support team and open a service request.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2010/05/01/correlation-ids-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx